# Auto complete with extra texts in dropdown

Tags: android, user-interface, autocomplete

I have this beer app that I use to log all the beers I drink (a bit like Untappd, but I'm the only user and own the data). When I enter the brewery for a beer I want to log, the app will auto complete with the names of any breweries already in my app. This can look a bit like this:

[image]

This uses an `AutoCompleteTextView` with the brewery names as the text. Here's the xml for the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="com.svendhhh.androidbeerapp.activities.LogBeerActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="top">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/input_brewery"
                android:labelFor="@+id/input_brewery_label"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:hint="@string/enter_brewery"
                android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size"
                android:completionThreshold="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/input_add_brewery_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:onClick="gotoAddBrewery" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/input_beer_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:hint="@string/enter_beer"
                android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size"
                android:completionThreshold="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/input_add_beer_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:onClick="gotoAddBeer" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/input_beer_rating"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="@string/enter_beer_rating"
            android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_size" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/input_beer_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:hint="@string/enter_date_and_time"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/input_submit_beer_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/log_beer"
            android:onClick="submitBeer"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see in this example, it can occasionally be difficult to tell which is the correct brewery, when there are multiple with very similar names. What I'd really like to do is show an extra hint, probably location and country, below the brewery name in a smaller greyed out font, a bit like this:

[image]

Is there any clever way of doing this? Maybe I need to use something other than `AutoCompleteTextView` to achieve this, or maybe I need to use a Dropdown and implement my own auto complete, just dynamically adding removing options to the dropdown as the user types?